# How to create an Archive file form flatfile with timestamp in informatica which should contain same target location?

Tags: business-intelligence, informatica, bi-tool

The Scenario is I have a flat file as source and I need to create 2 target files in same location. One is target file and other one is Archive file(along with time stamp)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create command task and archive the file with timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two target in mapping itself then you can parameterize the target file with $OutputfileName and assign a value something like "targetFileName-`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.log"